# What does a DisableLastAccess value of 3 mean?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, fsutil

On my Windows 10 system when i run the command:

`fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess`

it returns

`DisableLastAccess = 3  (System Managed, Enabled)`

I've never manually set this value and I can't seem to find out what the value of '3' means.
I came across https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior which only mentions 0/1 as options

Is there a doc somewhere that mentions what the value of '3' means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command prompt type:

```
fsutil behavior set DisableLastAccess
```

Hit enter and you will get this output:

Values:

0 - User Managed, Last Access Updates Enabled

1 - User Managed, Last Access Updates Disabled

2 - System Managed, Last Access Updates Enabled

3 - System Managed, Last Access Updates Disabled

Comment: So is 3 enabled or disabled? It seems to contradict itself.

Comment: 1 is disabled for the user, 3 is disabled for the entire system and all users, is my take on it.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Disabling DisableLastAccess enables writing the last access. So easy.

Answer (score 2):

The outdated [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior) has the following information:

> **Fsutil behavior**
> The `disablelastaccess` parameter reduces the impact of logging updates to the **LastAccessTime** stamp on files and directories. Disabling the **LastAccessTime** feature improves the speed of file and directory access. This parameter updates the following registry key:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate`

> *Notes:*
>
> File-based **LastAccessTime** queries are accurate even if all on-disk values are not current. NTFS returns the correct value on queries because the accurate value is stored in memory.

One hour is the maximum amount of time that NTFS defers updating **LastAccessTime** on disk. If NTFS updates other file attributes such as **LastModifyTime**, and a **LastAccessTime** update is pending, NTFS updates **LastAccessTime** with the other updates without additional performance impact.

> The `disableLastAccess` parameter can affect programs such as Backup and Remote Storage that rely on this feature.

As for *System Managed* versus *User Managed*, basically **System Managed** mode means that the system treats the corresponding enable/disable state that you selected as advisory only. Basically, each time the system boots, it will decide whether to enable or disable `LastAccessTime` updating based on empirical factors, possibly overriding your suggestion.

From https://dfir.ru/2018/12/08/the-last-access-updates-are-almost-back/ (with cosmetic edits)...

> In the **System Managed** mode, the NTFS driver can enable or disable **LastAccessTime** updating during the boot (in particular, when the system volume is mounted). **LastAccessTime** updates are enabled for NTFS volumes *when the size of the system volume is 128 GiB or less*. If the system volume is larger, then **LastAccessTime** updating is disabled.
>
> The volume size threshold can be modified by writing an integer to:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystemNtfsLastAccessUpdatePolicyVolumeSizeThreshold`

> The integer must specify the new threshold in GiB (not in bytes). The registry key doesn’t exist by default.

Use **User Managed** mode if you want to control the status of **LastAccessTime** updating and you don't want the system to override your choice during boot.