# possible to see which files I accessed on certain date/time?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, logging

I recently created a Photoshop image from a bunch of images on my computer and now I need to find one of the original images which I know is on my machine.

I know the final PSD was created on October-‎14-‎19, ‏‎10:47:30 PM, so what I am wondering is this:

Is there a way to  see which files I accessed on my computer on that date?Perhaps there is some log of opened files?

Running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: updated post. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done from Windows Explorer, by entering in the Search box for the
current folder an expression such as (with today's date in European format):

```
accessed:22/11/2019 .. 22/11/2019
```

This requires that the last-accessed date be enabled for the disk
(see [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1408920/what-does-a-disablelastaccess-value-of-3-mean)).

You could similarly search for "last-modified" by replacing above `accessed`
by `modified`.